# Used a state inside of another state but updating it doesn't update the outer state, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `JSX element` that I want to control its `CSS class` with a state, and the element itself is also nested in another state as below:

```
this.setState({
   content: <div className={this.state.cClass} />
})
```

The problem is, when I update the cClass state, I want the content state get updated as well but it stays the same.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: share codesandbox

Comment: @therakeshpurohit Here you go: [codeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-christian-g3sw9?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. once you return the content state it gets loaded into the DOM but after the `setTimeout` cClass state is updated but still it won't reflect in the DOM as class property is still "App" in the HTML DOM. which has no more reference to the `this.state.cClass`

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cClass: "App"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(
        {
          cClass: "App fade"
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.cClass);
        }
      );
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.cClass}>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit naughty-sammet-l7zef]

Comment: Thank you @TheRakeshPurohit, I know if I put the elements outside of the state in render method, I can change class easily by `cClass state`, but the thing is elements **must** be nested in a state so after some process like loading etc, the elements can be changed completely as well. And I know that I can re-enter the whole content into `content state` but it's not a suitable way for just changing a single css class.

Comment: With your proposed approach, it's not achievable as I mentioned that `this.state.cClass` has no reference once `this.state.content` is loaded on DOM.

Comment: So if it's not possible this way, how can I select for example the first element inside `content state` and alter it ? I mean some method other than `document.getElementBy...`

Answer (score 0):

try use callback

```
this.setState((prevState)=>({
   content: <div className={prevState.cClass} />
})
```

// edited lifecycle

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   if(prevState.cClass !== state.cClass){
       this.setState({
          content: <div className={prevState.cClass} />
       })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention but this is not the problem; I want the `content state` get updated whenever the `cClass state` changes. and I cannot put the `div` element outside of state because after loading process it needs to be changed completely as well.

Comment: oh i see,

try use lifecycle method.
check out edited code

Comment: I built a custom function for this approach but now that you mention, I see using `componentDidUpdate` is more legit. thank you.

Comment: still it won't have the reference of the new value.

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit Yes I see, using this approach can cause problems in some cases but it is what it is, no other choices for now I guess! I hope they implement the reference in the next versions of React.